# Can we use ignore_user_abort() on any line of code?

Tags: php

Can we use ignore_user_abort on any line of PHP like:

```
<?php
// Process Codes
if($_GET['nonstop']) {
    ignore_user_abort(1);
    // Background process
}else{
     // Nonbackground process
}
// Other Codes
?>
```

Or we need to use on only after `<?php` (first line)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to use it anywhere you want within your code.

**Die & Exit**

ignore_user_abort() doesn't disable die or exit. It just tells PHP (and the server) to NOT abort the script when the remote users' connection closes.

**Worth Noting**

"PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client. Simply using an echo statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see flush(). " - PHP.Net

Comment: Hmm, oke. Thanks. Can we stop background process with die(); ?

Comment: ignore_user_abort doesn't disable die/exit. It just tells PHP (and apache) to NOT shut down the script when the remote users' connection closes.

Answer (score 0):

It is a PHP function... it needs to be within a `<?php  ?>` block.

If it isn't clear, you can have multiple PHP blocks.  You can always stick  at the top of your page (and you probably should, if this is the behavior you want!).